# Python Pivot: Can I get the count of columns per row(id/index) and store it in a new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

hope you can help me this.
The df looks like this.

region  AMER

```
 country    Brazil      Canada  Columbia    Mexico      United States                                                   
 metro  Rio de Janeiro  Sao Paulo   Toronto Bogota  Mexico City Monterrey   Atlanta Boston  Chicago Culpeper    Dallas  Denver  Houston Los Angeles Miami   New York    Philadelphia    Seattle Silicon Valley  Washington D.C.

ID                                                                              
321321      2   1   1           13  15  29      1   2   1   11  6   15  3   2   14  3
23213                               3                                               
231                         2   2   3       1       5   6   3   3   4   3   3   4
23213                               4   1       1           1       4   1   2   27  1
21321                               4   2                   2   1   14  3   2   4   2
12321       1   2                   1                       1           1   1   10  
123213      2                       45                  5           1               
12321                                                               1               
123                 1       3                           2
```

I want to get the count of columns that have data per of metro and country per region of all the rows(id/index) and store that count into a new column.

Regards,
RJ

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
df['new']df.sum(level=0, axis=1)
```